# Django and the POST request: unexpected behaviour with a form

Tags: html, django, forms, post

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
import myproject.views

urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'^$', myproject.views.home), (r'^login$', apolla.views.login))
```

**views.py**

```
import django.http
import django.template
import django.shortcuts

def home(request):
    return django.http.HttpResponse("Welcome home!")

def login(request):
    un = request.POST.get('username')
    pa = request.POST.get('password')
    di = {'unam': un, 'pass': pa}   
    if un and pa:
        di['act'] = "/"
    else:
        di['act'] = "/login"
    return django.shortcuts.render_to_response('login.html', di, 
      context_instance=django.template.RequestContext(request))    
    # Why does this code not send me immediately to "/" with 
    # username and password filled in?
```

**login.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="input" method="post" action="{{ act }}">
{% csrf_token %}
Username: 
<input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password: 
<input type="password" name="password"><br> 
<input id="su" type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the development server and go to `localhost:8000/login` and fill in a `username` and `password` and push the submit button I am not sent to `localhost:8000/` as I expected from my login function in `views.py`, I just return to `localhost:8000/login`. But when I fill in any field and submit for the second time I get directed to `localhost:8000`.

I also used `print un` and `print pa` to see if the post caught the data from the `username` and `password` fields and it did from the first time, so why am I not being directed to `localhost:8000/login` from the first submit with both `username` and `password` fields filled in?

Comment: Why should it send you to `/`? At no point do you redirect. The only thing the view does is display the form, with a `action` depending on whether you've previously filled in the fields. There's absolutely no reason why that should redirect you.

Comment: After filling out the form once w/ `username/pw`, the action changes to point to `/` on the second round which will submit the form TO `/` which presumably has no idea how to handle this form. As Daniel says, there is no redirection anywhere in this code. This is exactly expected behavior.

Comment: Could anyone show how I could redirect to `/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add redirects to your view by:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def foo_view(request):
    # ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```